# Sort multilayer object by lower level item

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an object that looks like this

```
[{group: 'Group-B', items[{ count : 3, item : 'item-A' }]},
 {group: 'Group-B', items[{ count : 8, item : 'item-C' }]},
 {group: 'Group-A', items[{ count : 4, item : 'item-H' }]},
 {group: 'Group-C', items[{ count : 2, item : 'item-F' }]}
]
```

The RESULT should read:  `desc by count`

```
[{group: 'Group-B', items[{ count : 8, item : 'item-C' }]},
 {group: 'Group-A', items[{ count : 4, item : 'item-H' }]},
 {group: 'Group-B', items[{ count : 3, item : 'item-A' }]},
 {group: 'Group-C', items[{ count : 2, item : 'item-F' }]}
]
```

I need to sort this whole object by `count`.
Ive been looking at `lodash`, but I cant figure out how to do this.

[image]

Comment: Here it is answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-objects-by-property-values

Comment: Do you need to sort the main array? Or separately each array of `items` of the main array?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it so

```js
const array = [
 {group: 'Group-B', items:[{ count : 3, item : 'item-A' }]},
 {group: 'Group-B', items:[{ count : 8, item : 'item-C' }]},
 {group: 'Group-A', items:[{ count : 4, item : 'item-H' }]},
 {group: 'Group-C', items:[{ count : 2, item : 'item-F' }]}
]

const result = array.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.items[0].count - b.items[0].count
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

hope it helps. you can remove .slice() function if you don't want to create a copy of original array.

```js
let obj = [
    {group: 'Group-B', items: [{count: 3, item: 'item-A'}]},
    {group: 'Group-B', items: [{count: 8, item: 'item-C'}]},
    {group: 'Group-A', items: [{count: 4, item: 'item-H'}]},
    {group: 'Group-C', items: [{count: 2, item: 'item-F'}]}
]
console.log(obj)

let sorted = obj.slice().sort((a,b) => {
    if(a.items[0].count < b.items[0].count){
        return -1
    }
    if(a.items[0].count > b.items[0].count){
        return 1
    }
    else
        return 0
});
console.log(sorted)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort by the number of elements in items, you could do this:

```
myArray.sort(function(itemA, itemB) {return itemA.items.count - itemB.items.count; });
```

if you want to sort by the attribute "count" that is in each element in the array `items`, you will have to detail how you compare these elements. But what you are looking for must be the Array.sort() function: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/sort